# Why do we use the plural of the definite article in the name of certain countries?

Tags: articles, toponymes

Why use a plural article in, for example:

- les États-Unis
- les Émirats arabes unis
- les Pays-bas

?

Comment: This is only partly related to French, as many other languages have the same feature regarding the same countries.

Comment: Moreover (in addition with comment above), the article is not *in the name* It is not part of the name. It's sometimes used with it for the reason given in @radouxju 's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of the countries mentioned in the question are based on a composition of units, therefore the article is plural. However, most of the countries are "singular". The other exceptions include countries composed of many islands: *Les Seychelles, les Philippines*...

*Les États-Unis d'Amérique* (federal republic composed of 50 states)

*Les Émirats arabes unis* (Federal monarchy composed of 7 emirates)

*Les Pays-Bas* (historically, 7 independent provinces united to create the Provinces-Unies, which evolved through the time to become today's *Royaume des Pays-Bas*)